# How to use a different visualization tool (Or a Java package) with anylogic instead of a chromedriver

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I'm new to simulation modeling and I've been modeling a factory with some heavy 3D models. The functionality part of the simulation is fine but it struggles to render the model in the chromedriver since it's CPU rendered. Is there any way to make it GPU rendered or Is there any way to use a different tool/Java Package to render the simulation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not natively possible.

You'd need to use your own rendering engine (Unreal, Unity, ...) and link it up via API calls yourself.

This is possible but not documented anywhere, afaik. Check this [case study](https://www.anylogic.com/upload/conference/2019/presentations/transocean-drilling-rig-digital-twin-and-virtual-well-construction-simulation.pdf) where it was done with the Unreal gaming engine.

Comment: Thank you very much. I agree. There are almost no documentation about the process.